# Get field annotations of class from child field

Tags: java, reflection

Is there any method to get value of @AnnotationB of bClass from fieldC?

```
Class A {
    @AnnotationB("a")
    B bClass;
}

Class B{
     String fieldC;
}
```

Currently I can get only declaring annotations of bClass as Class:

```
...
fieldC.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(AnnotationB.class)
...
```

In this case annotation will be not found.

Comment: It will not be found because there is none? You cannot magically have annotations on fields which are not annotated

Comment: bClass field is annotated. And I want to get value of this annotation when I'm on fieldC.